# Why do i need to close the comet event to send the data ? (tomcat 6)

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, comet

I use comet on tomcat 6 to push data from the server as described here : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cometjava/

My problem is simple : if i don't do a `event.close();` after my `writer.print` and `writer.flush`, then the data does not seem to be sent to the client, since the `onreadystatechange` of the `XMLHttpRequest` is not called.

Is it normal?

Because of that, I need to send a new request to the server every time i receive data, because the connection needs to be closed to send data.

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not normal for Chrome, Safari, FireFox. Because on event readystate.LOADED it can process data from server on client side

```
/**
* @param {string} url
* @param {function(*)} callback 
* @param {boolean} reload */
archiva.io.streamXhr = function(url, callback) {

    var xhr = new goog.net.XhrIo();
    var lastIndex = -1;
    var delimiter = '\n';

    goog.events.listen(xhr, goog.net.EventType.READY_STATE_CHANGE, function() {
        // As more data is loaded, look for the next delimiter so the JSON can // be extracted, parsed, and passed to the callback.

        if ( xhr.getReadyState() > goog.net.XmlHttp.ReadyState.LOADED ) {
            var str = xhr.getResponseText();
            var index;
            while ((index = str.indexOf(delimiter, lastIndex + 1)) != -1) {
                var json = str.substring(lastIndex + 1, index);
                callback(json);
                lastIndex = index;
            }
        }

        if (xhr.isComplete()) {
            // Reconnect if the response finishes for any reason.
            archiva.io.streamXhr(url, callback);
            xhr.dispose();
        }
    });

    xhr.send(url, 'POST'); 
};
```

and xhr.getReadyState() no such browsers will be 3 and **getResponseText()** will return response text (when server side execute writer.flush() and no need to writer.close() ).

But due to IE < 10 it is not possible **getResponseText()** on state = 3, only state == 4. And state 4 is state for closed. This is why you need close connection after flush data, because other case IE will continue loading data and never process it. But it is possible manage amount of data on server side and after close;

look at this link, how to implement [tomcat 7 comet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/aio.html)

Hope this help